# How to get a CUDA/GPU/device pointer in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, gpu

I have an `image` read and decoded from a video file using OpenCV (cv2). I also have an image I have read using OpenCV only once (`mask`). My model reads pairs `mask`-`image`. How to make sure the mask is moved/created on GPU only once? How to say something like `.to_device()` or `.cuda()` on an OpenCV decoded image for TensorFlow use?